# How to make a react component that is a table with different sized columns and rows

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make this into a react component so I can use it in my website:

[image]

I don't know how to go about making this or, if any libraries are involved, I don't know which ones.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What have you looked into?

Comment: I looked into bootstrap, but I don't think it's possible to make a table like this. I'm thinking that this can be done in the html for that component, maybe using bootstrap, but I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: If you wanna make tables then there are react modules for that like [react-table](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table). That modules also lets you use custom React components as table cells (as well as PLENTY of other customisation). From the picture I'm not really sure what you want. Is that a picture of ONE table cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like this component will take a few properties:

```
const CardsDisplay = ({numCards}) => { /* ... */ }

const AvatarDisplay = ({imageUrl, numCards, name, score, popupMenu }) =>
  <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
    <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
      <img src={imageUrl} />
      <CardsDisplay numCards={numCards} />
    </div>
    {name}
    <br />
    {score.toLocaleString()}
    <popupMenu style={{float: 'right'}} />
  </div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.